# Using payment gateway from xamarin cross platform app

Tags: xamarin.forms, payment-gateway

Is it possible to implement the payment gateway solution in a cross-platform xamarin application.

From a web app we can implement that and the payment page  will be opened in gateway provider page. But when it comes to cross platform mobile app we are using xaml pages to design the android pages and  have to handle the payment options from this xaml views.

Comment: Have you looked into Paypal.Forms? I am currently trying it however I am not sure how googple feels about it just yet

Answer (score 3):

Apple only requires In App purchases if the payment is for digital goods. If you are paying for physical goods, for instance (like my app Waitress.com does), Apple actually mandates that you CANNOT use in app purchases. Same thing with Google.

As to the question (if you are selling physical goods), I am currently looking for the same thing, a payment provider with a .NET client SDK that can work cross platform for Xamarin. If you only need iOS and Android the best option I have found seems to be Stripe, which has a xamarin component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/stripe

For UWP I am contemplating using a web view to tokenize the cards... not very elegant, but could perhaps work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Yes.

However any purchases done from within your app on iOS will have to use Apple In App Purchases or Apple will not accept it into the store.

Google TOS likewise requires that any purchases done within your app utilizes Google In app Billing or it can be removed from their store. So though it is possible to create a single billing handler that uses say paypal for both ios and droid purchases. No one has bothered since there is no way to distribute such an app.

You can code an interface for billing in your forms app. Then use an IOC container to inject different versions of that interface on each platform. In iOS use the InAppPurchase Componet and for Droid use the InAppBilling componet. Both componets work basically the same. Different methods etc but same basic concept.